# Known lower bounds on halting for finite machines?

Tags: complexity-theory, halting-problem

It's possible to determine whether a deterministic machine with finite memory will halt in O(n) time if the machine has n possible states. You simply run the machine until it halts or visits the same state twice, which is guaranteed to happen in no more than n steps.

Can any other algorithm do this in fewer steps? Is there a proof that no such algorithm can exist?

Comment: Could you specify what exactly is your machine model? Are you looking at a DFA? if so - it always runs in $O(n)$, since essentially it just reads the word. If not, what model exactly are you using?

Comment: I'm not talking about a DFA that reads a given number of input symbols and then halts. Rather, I'm talking about a machine that starts at one state and then just moves from one state to another until it reaches a halting state. A Turing machine with a finite tape would be reducible to this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just have a sequence of nodes, each has a transition to the next one, and you want to find the length of the sequence in less than $O(n)$ time?

Comment: Please explain how any (sub-Turing) machine with finite memory can accept languages a DFA (or compute functions that a finite-tape TM) can not.

Comment: All DFAs always "halt" once there's not any more input. If you're asking whether you can tell that the language is non-empty, everything that comes to mind requires $O(|Q|)$, so I don't know if you'll do better than that.

Comment: @Raphael I think that is the answer to this question. Every such machine is equivalent to some DFA. Then, the lower bounds for accepting a string could be given in terms of a minimal version of the automata.

Comment: I'm guessing @Taymon is talking about a "Linear Bounded Automaton" (LBA): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton

Comment: As the wiki article suggests, the memory of an LBA is linear in the size of the input, not fixed. Maybe the question should describe precisely the computational model in mind?

Comment: I assume that the asker is thinking about constant space TMs. DSPACE(O(1)) is equivalent to REG. Despite the classes being equivalent, an FSM is still a different model of computation. For a DTM, you would need to check that it loops back to the same machine *configuration* (both state of the state machine AND layout of the tape). You can turn it into an FSM with no memory by increasing the number of states (a constant factor more). I think the question is asking if you can do significantly better than this.

Comment: @mdx, in place of you interpreting the question the OP should edit it to make question clear so it doesn't need interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your machine runs without any further input once it is
started. Whatever input it has is encoded in its starting state. Since
your machine is deterministic, there is at most a single transition
from each state. So the state-transition graph of your automaton is a
directed graph composed of paths that either are isolated cycles or
are simply open linear path from an initial node/state to a final node
(corresponding to a halting state without transition). There may be
any (positive) number of such paths, possibly only one. Actually, only one of these paths is relevant, the one containing the initial state.

Depending on whether the initial state of your automaton is on a
cyclic path or on an open path, the automaton will run for ever or
halt at the end of the open path. The former is identified by checking
whether a state is visited twice. The latter is identified by the fact
that a halting state (without transition) is encountered.

In the question, you do not give any constraint or information on the way states and
transitions are defined, other than the following:

- from a given state, there is a transition function that gives you
  the next state;
- you can know whether two states are the same or not.

So the only way you can map the graph structure to reason about it is
to follow the transition function from state to state, even when
knowing the total number of states $n$.

With $n$ states, you can have a graph $C_n$ composed of one cycle of
$n$ states. You can also have a graph $L_n$ composed of one open
linear path of $n$ states starting with the initial state and ending
with a halting state. The former is non-halting, while the latter is
halting.

Still assuming you know the number of states, and using only the gven
primitives, the only way to find a difference is to follow $n-1$
transition. Then you are either in a halting or a non-halting state.
The former tells you that computation halts, while the latter tells
you it does not halt.

You clearly will not do better when you do not know $n$ in
advance. Actually, you then need only one more transition to detect that
the computation is not halting.

So there is no way to decide whether your automaton halts in fewer
steps, unless you have other means for analyzing the state-transition
graph.

In other words, the only way you can have a faster algorithm is to
have some formalism that structures the state-transition graph with
properties that can be used to analyze it without having to follow the
transitions.

Comment: Which model of computation are you tailoring your answer to?

Comment: @mdx I did not consider any specific model. I just took the question for
what it says: there is a device that makes transitions
deterministically from state to state, without taking any input,
beginning at some starting state. The number of states is finite, and
it is possible to know if a state has been previously encountered.  It
could be a deterministic LBA, or a DFA bundled with an input and an
index on the input, or a bounded stack DPDA with its input, etc. Having
more information on what it is might suggest a better way of deciding
termination, but the OP does not say.

Comment: If the machine has memory, looking at repeated states isn't enough. You need to have the same tape/memory configuration too. Perhaps a determinstic O(1) space turing machine would best fit the question?

Comment: @mdx I see what you mean, but I assumed that the OP made sense, and I took
state to mean memory configuration, since it is the only way his
statement can be correct. States in the DFA sense can always be
represented by memory configurations, and we routinely use one for the
other.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in constant time.
We already know that the machine halts.
So we just output "YES".

The issue is that you have to explain what is the domain of the inputs to the problem.
If the domain of the inputs only contains machines which halt then the problem is trivial: 
all of them halt, there is nothing to check.

(You have to specify what is given as input if you want another answer.)

Comment: I think the input would just be like the normal halting problem. Input = $\langle M, x\rangle$ where $M$ is the machine and $x$ is the input. I don't see anything assuming that the machine in question necessarily halts.

Comment: It says "determine whether _a deterministic machine with finite memory_ will ..." and "which _is guaranteed to happen_ in no more than n steps". Of the input is not that then the OP should clarify what is the input.

Comment: I think OP is thinking of the naive algorithm for deciding the halting problem on these constant space machines. For FSMs, you just simulate then check if a state is ever repeated (which happens in n steps or less) or if it just halts. For constant space TMs, you would check if a machine configuration is encountered twice. My interpretation of the question is that its asking if there is a complexity lower bound for answering this question. In other words, can we prove that we cannot do better than the naive algorithm?